# How to install ubuntu on lenovo ideapad y510p?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Lenovo ideapad y510p with a pre installed Windows 8, however I also want to have in my laptop Ubuntu 13. 10 which I'm still new to the OS but my job requires it. I have burned the iso file to a DVD and tried to installed it but no use (even though it turns to a black screen which then it requires to use an external screen since it doesn't recogonize the Intel graphical card). Moreover, my friend tried with the USB stick but I think the problem concerns with recognizing the VGA card with a message about the noveu or something like this.

So my main question is how to install Ubuntu 13.10 in Lenovo ideapad y510p and I would really appreciate if you could provide me with a simple guide of installation since I have a little background on the Linux environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 also has black screen. 12.04 can be installed up to the point it said "failed to install grub-efi to /target/."

Comment: Did you read the link?

Answer (score 0):

I am had the same problem with you and how I solved it is through a few methods:

1. Press 'e' at the option of 'Install Ubuntu' and then add the parameter of 'nomodeset', next to splash.
2. The black screen is probably because your brightness is set at the lowest. Go on and press Fn + Up to increase brightness.

Everything should be fine then! :)